# What causes to function call (sinx/cosx) to return value 0

Tags: c, function

Im trying to call a single function call to calculate `sinx()` & `cosx()` but for some reason `sinx()` returns value `0` for each time.

```
// homework 4, part 1,
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// function call for factorial.
int factorial(int n) {
  int temp = n;
  int sum = 1;
  while (temp > 0) {
    sum *= temp;
    temp -= 1;
  }
  return sum;
}

// function call for numenator.
numenator(int n) {
  int numenator = pow(-1, n);
  return numenator;
}

// function call for powX.
powX(int x, int n) {
  int powX = pow(x, n);
  return powX;
}

// function call for x & n inputs.
/* function is not working */
int getInputs(int x, int n) {
  printf("Enter integer as degree: ");
  scanf(" %d", &x);
  printf("Enter integer as degree: ");
  scanf(" %d", &n);
  if (x == 'E' || n == 'E') {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
}

// function call to find sine.
double sinx(int x, int n) {
  double sine;
  double temp = 0.0;
  while (n > 0) {
    // program -n yapınca 2*n+1 değişiyor
    // temp üzerinden değişiklik yapınca, aynı döngü...
    // ...temp 0 olana kadar devam ediyor.
    sine = numenator(n) / factorial(2*n+1) * powX(x, 2*n+1);
    temp += sine;
    printf("sin(%d) where n is %d = %f\n", x, n, temp);
    n -= 1;
  }
}

// function call to find cosine.
double cosx(int x, int n) {
  double cosine = 0.0;
  double temp = 0.0;
  while (n > 0) {
    cosine = numenator(n) / factorial(2*n) * powX(x, 2*n);
    temp += cosine;
    n -= 1;
    printf("\ncos(%d) where n is %d = %f", x, n, temp);
  }
}

// main section of program.
int main() {
  int x = 30, n = 4;
  //getInputs(x, n);
  sinx(x, n);
  cosx(x, n);
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to see where problem comes from, so wrote down every function one-by-one to see if it works properly but I am loosing track on functions `sinx` and `cosx`.

Here is the formula I'm using on sub functions (numenator/factorial/powX):

[image: Formula to find sinx/cosx]

Comment: Neither `sinx()` nor `cosx()` have a `return` statement, and `numenator()` and `powX()` don't have a return type.

Comment: Functions in modern C need to have the return type declared. If you are learning C from a source that does not declare the return type on functions, drop that source and find a better.

Comment: Time to upgrade to a better compiler or to set up your present one correctly - see [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The computations give surprising results because you use integer arithmetics instead of floating point arithmetics for many of the expressions:

- `x` should be defined as a `double` instead of `int` in `main`, `sinx`, `cosx` and `powX`
- `sinx` and `cosx` should return the result.
- `powX` should have a return type `double`.
- `numenator` should have a return type `int` and be renamed `numerator`.
- in function `numenator` you define a local variable with the same name as the function: this is confusing.  Furthermore, you should use `if (n % 2 == 1) return -1; else return 1;` instead of `pow(-1, n)`.
- `int getInputs(int x, int n)` should take pointers to the destination variables.
- `x` should be read with a `%f` conversion
- `temp` should be used for the term, not the result.
- the initial value of `temp` should be `1.0` for `cosx`. As coded, `cosx` is missing the first term.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should get weird results (undefined behaviour) in both functions, as you never return a value neither for `sinx`, nor for `cosx`.

You should return the value of `temp` in both cases, but you don't use the value of it, once you accumulate all the terms in the series.

Answer (score 0):

At least these issues:

**Save time enable all warnings**

**Missing return values from functions**

**Floating point math**

`numenator(n) / factorial(2*n+1` is integer division with an integer quotient.  Use floating point division.

```
1.0 * numenator(n) / factorial(2*n+1)
```

Consider using `double` in more places like

```
// double sinx(int x, int n)
double sinx(double x, int n)
// powX(int x, int n) {
double powX(double x, int n) {
...
```